# sh: How to extend environment variables?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, sh

Everywhere you can read how to *replace* environment variables. But I want to ***insert*** a new path at the beginning of my $PATH variable. What's the simplest way to do this using sh?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just assign it a new value that includes the old:

```
PATH=/new/path:${PATH}
```

Comment: Thanks. Because of a white space in the path which I wanted to insert, I used `PATH='/cygdrive/c/Program Files/cygwin/bin':${PATH}` - everything worked correctly.

Comment: Yep, good. Or you could single quote the whole thing: `PATH="/new/path:${PATH}"`

Comment: @AlexHowansky: You mean "double quote" (which is what you show). Single quotes won't allow the variable to be expanded.

Comment: Oops typo, yes -- double quote.